# TIBCO.EMS.IllegalStateException: connect failed: server in standby mode

Tags: c#, tibco-ems

We have a big system with bunch of services communicating with each other via TIBCO EMS Messaging.
Now, one of the services keeps throwing this exception when it tries to connect to EMS server:

```
TIBCO.EMS.IllegalStateException: connect failed: server in standby mode
```

However, other services on the same EMS server are working just fine without any exception.

I tried to reproduce this by creating a console application which would use same credentials to connect to EMS server on the same destination (Queue) but couldn't reproduce this error.

EMS connection is fault-tolerant and it might have been failed over to secondary server, however, now I see primary server is back up.

I also tried to connect to primary server only (which I can see is up & running) but it fails with the same exception.

Below is the stack trace for reference:

```
TIBCO.EMS.IllegalStateException: connect failed: server in standby mode
   at TIBCO.EMS.CFImpl._CreateConnection(String userName, String password, Boolean xa)
   at TIBCO.EMS.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(String userName, String password)
   at Ems.makeConn()
```

We're using `TIBCO.EMS.dll v. 8.1.0.10` on `.NET 4.0`.

Any idea what can cause this exception ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out tools we were using to check if server is active (we don't have admin rights on the servers) was misbehaving (showing incorrect status), so none of those servers were really active (not primary nor secondary).
As soon as server was brought up this error message went away.

Answer (score 1):

Could your connection string only mention one of the hosts inside an FT/HA setup ? This looks like the error message returned when you are trying to connect to only one of the HA/FT host, but not the one active at the moment.

If it is the case, the connection string will work *most* of the time, but a *proper* EMS HA connection string include two (or more!) EMS host and port. Only one is active at the same time.

It typically looks like this:

```
serverUrl=tcp://server0:7222, tcp://server1:7344
```

See source doc here [in TIBCO docs](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/ems/8.4.0/doc/pdf/TIB_ems_8.4_users_guide.pdf).

Comment: Yeph, this is how connection string looks like. After having this connection string and still getting the error, I left only active one. By the way was flipping connections as well (leaving only first and then only second) but it didn't help.